# Can I drive in Oregon with an International Driver's license from Iraq?

Tags: usa, driving, driving-licenses, oregon

I have an International Driver's license issued in Iraq which is still valid, and I am a refuge here. Can I drive a car in Portland, Oregon?

Comment: "Oregon permits a non-US citizen to drive for up to one year with an International Driver's Permit in the State" as per "[How to Apply for a New Driver's License in Oregon](https://www.dmv.com/or/oregon/drivers-license)", DMV.com.

Comment: Raheem - please read site scope before posting. This has nothing to do with Information Security! I'll migrate to Travel, but it may not have enough info for that site...

Comment: You have the international driving permit, which is a translation of the Iraqi license. Do you also have a valid Iraqi driving license itself? You usually need the actual government-issued license and not just the IDP. In any case, you are [supposed to](http://www.oregon.gov/ODOT/DMV/pages/driverid/licensenonres.aspx) get an Oregon driver's license once you become a resident of Oregon. It will be useful to have one for ID purposes anyway, so I'd recommend you get started on that process.

Answer (score 4):

I have  the same concern.

however, since I obtained a residential address in Oregon already, this means the validity of my international driving permit is only good for a month instead of one year so I have to obtain an Oregon drivers license to legally drive around Oregon.  I can no longer use my international driving permit for more than a month after I obtained my residential address here in Oregon.

Answer (score 3):

The validity of your International Driving Permit is of no consequence.  If your Iraq Driving License is still valid AND you have both your IDP & Iraqi license in your possession, then yes you can drive in Oregon and the rest of the USA.

If your Iraqi driving license has expired, then no you can not drive until you either renew it or obtain an Oregon Driving License.  (I am guessing based on your status the first is not an option)

If your Iraqi driving license is still valid, but not in your possession (ie it got left behind), then you also need to obtain a new Oregon DL.